# Method for selecting different local host database with shared code

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using this simple function to connect to a `named_database`.  But the code and its associated project are used on more than one site.  I'm tired of having to constantly edit the DB_PASS settings etc.

```
function select_named_db()
 {

  $link = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
  $result=mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME  ) ;
  return $link;
 }
```

How would I alter my function so that it could try 2 or 3 different database settings so the script can figure out which host, user and password set to use?

Would be it something simple like this?

```
if (!mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)) 
   {
      $link = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     } elseif (!mysqli_connect( DB_HOST2, DB_USER2, DB_PASS2))
       {
        $link=mysqli_connect( DB_HOST2, DB_USER2, DB_PASS2);
         }
```

Or is there a better procedural method?

Answer (score 0):

settings.php:

```
if (ENV == 'dev') {
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    // and so on
} elseif(ENV == 'production') {
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    // and so on
}
```

then define ENV somewhere in bootstrap file or webserver config

Comment: I looked into this.  Apparently auto-discovery of the ENV depends a lot on the version of PHP and the server.

Comment: There is no reason to be rude.

Comment: Nothing rude is here. Just a statement of fact.

Answer (score 0):

isn't it better to pass a parameter to select_named_db()?

You could have an array of DB connections:

$DB_HOST[0]=...

$DB_USER[0]=...

and depending the page where you call from, use a DB or another. This parameter could be defined in the function or be passed in session, as you wish...

Comment: Yes I'm going to do something similar but via `select_named_db('dbname')`.

Comment: Again, you are rude.  Please stay out of this question if you can't be nice.

Comment: I think the point is that you haven't understood his problem, maybe because he has not explained it clearly. Anyway, he has the solution now :)